# First list in TikZ Poster is wrongly spaced

Tags: spacing, itemize, tikzposter

When using `tikzposter`, the first `itemize` is handled differently, namely the space to the adjacent paragraphs are off:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\begin{document}
        \block{}{
            XXXXXXXXXXX
            \begin{itemize}
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
            \end{itemize}
            XXXXXXXXXXX
            \begin{itemize}
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
            \end{itemize}
            XXXXXXXXXXX
        }
\end{document}
```

[image: illustration of spacing problem]

Is there a simple way to fix this, except manually adjusting the spacing with whatever happens to be the first list? (I am intending to submit a bug report on this, but given that the package is more or less asleep, I might as well come with a solution or ideally a pull request.)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}` is seems a simple solution.

Comment: @ferahfeza: Okay, I maybe should have specified that I do not want to tinker with the spacing manually for the first list – which that solution would require me to do unless I misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1):

`enumitem` package can solve this.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}

\begin{document}
        \block{}{
            XXXXXXXXXXX
            \begin{itemize}
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
            \end{itemize}
            XXXXXXXXXXX
            \begin{itemize}
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
                \item XXXXXXXXXXX
            \end{itemize}
            XXXXXXXXXXX
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can `enumitem` also solve this with a different spacing than a regular linespace? As soon as I change its space settings, the problem reappears. Your example essentially solves the problem by reducing the spacing for other lists to the “wrong” spacing of the first one.